# How to pass a function as a callback of another function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have `db-conn.js` where I store my `db connection` in a `function`, then I `require` it in the `create.js` file and `call` it.

What I want is to `pass` the rest of the code as a `callback` to it, so that firstly it `connects` to the database and then it does the `insertion`.

As I am not quite good at callbacks I don´t know how to do it. Could you please help me?

So this the db-conn.js:

```
var mongo = {}
/**************************************************/
mongo.doConnection = (fcallback) => {
    mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    global.db = null
    sDatabasePath = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/kea'
    global.mongoId = require('mongodb').ObjectID

    /**************************************************/
    mongo.connect(sDatabasePath, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR 003 -> Cannot connect to the database')
            return false
        }
        global.db = db
        console.log('OK 002 -> Connected to the database')
    })
}
/**************************************************/
module.exports = mongo
```

and this is the create.js:

```
var mongo = require(__dirname + '/db-conn.js')
/**************************************************/
mongo.doConnection()// I am not sure what to do here 
createStudent = () => {
    var jStudent =
        {
            "firstName": "Sarah",
            "lastName": "Jepsen",
            "age": 27,
            "courses": [
                {
                    "courseName": "Web-development",
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "Santiago",
                            "lastName": "Donoso"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "courseName": "Databases",
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "Dany",
                            "lastName": "Kallas"
                        },
                        {
                            "firstName": "Rune",
                            "lastName": "Lyng"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "courseName": "Interface-Design",
                    "teachers": [
                        {
                            "firstName": "Roxana",
                            "lastName": "Stolniceanu"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    global.db.collection('students').insertOne(jStudent, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> create.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "create.js -> saved -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the connect is finished in db-conn.js you need to call the `fcallback` callback.

```
mongo.connect(sDatabasePath, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 003 -> Cannot connect to the database')
        return fcallback(err, null);
    }
    global.db = db
    console.log('OK 002 -> Connected to the database')
    return fcallback(null, db);
})
```

Then in create js you need to add a callback function as a parameter to `mongo.doConnection(...)` which will be called when the connection is finished (fcallback is called)

With this callback, you can ensure `createStudent` will be called when the connection is finished.

```
mongo.doConnection( (err, db) => {
    if(err){
      console.error("error connection to db: " + err;
      return;
    }
    createStudent = () => {
        var jStudent =
            { } ...

});
```

Comment: Do I need to specify the err for the connection again when I execute mongo.doConnection?  Isn´t that redundant?

Comment: no you do not. It is redundant. error-first callbacks follow a first parameter is err and second param is data, so I followed that. If you want you can even just ignore both params and do `return fcallback();` in connect, and remove them in `mongo.doConnection`

Comment: yeah that´s what I did. ...and then in create.js I just do `mongo.doConnection(createStudent)`after defining `createStudent()`, and it works perfectly. Thank´s.